# why description of the head disapear after removing some columns?

Tags: r, dataframe, rstudio

I have a data set and head of it (name of columns ) are like this

[image]

when I make a new data fram and remove some columns the head's description disappear.

```
 df<-da34714.0001[,]
 df<-df[,-4:-6]
```

and df is like  this

[image]

Answer (score 1):

These lie in an [attribute of the `data.frame` columns called `label` which Rstudio visualises](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/205175388-Using-the-Data-Viewer#labels). Many operation that modify objects in R don't preserve such non-essential attributes so one has to be careful.

In your example it seems you want to remove some columns from the data.frame. One way to accomplish this while keeping the labels intact is:

*Data*

```
df <- iris
attr(df$Species, "label") <- "This is the Species column"
```

[image]

*Now drop some columns*

```
df[c(1,2)] <- NULL
```

[image]

Comment: I have 150 columns should I do it one by one for all of them?

Comment: @sherek_66 do what?

Comment: you did it for 1 column, I have 150 columns

Comment: I'm not clear what your question is. How to add in an attribute to all columns again after losing them. Then you can use a loop of some kind.

Comment: To store them while doing some operation that might drop the attributes you can do `x <- lapply(df, attr, "label")` but that's a separate questions